# invalid object name 'purchase_report'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using two databases `PC_PARTS` table name is `STOCKS` and 2nd database is `PURCHASE_STOCK` table name is `PURCHASE REPORT`

The first part of the query is running because it updates the table but the 2nd part is not inserting the query and showing me a msgbox

> INVALID OBJECT NAME 'purchase_report'

Here's my code

```
 Private Sub Button8_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click   
 '''''''''''''''1st part'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 Dim qtyrelease As Integer
    qtyrelease = pqty.Text - prelease.Value


    Dim release As String = String.Empty
    release &= "update stocks set "
    release &= "quantity=@qty "
    release &= "where build_number=@build"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=pc_parts;user=admin;password=12345;")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = release
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qtyrelease)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@build", pbuildnumber.Text)
            End With

            Try
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Purchase Complete!")
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    '''''''''''''''2nd part''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim purchase As String = String.Empty
    purchase &= "insert into puchase_report(buildnumber,pcbrand,pcpart,qty,date_purchase)"
    purchase &= "values"
    purchase &= "(@build1,@brand,@part,@quantity,@date)"

    Using conn1 As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=purchase_stock;user=admin_report;password=54321;")
        Using cmd1 As New SqlCommand
            With cmd1
                .Connection = conn1
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = purchase
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@build1", pbuildnumber.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", pbrand.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@part", ppart.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", prelease.Value)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", pdate.Text)
            End With

            Try
                conn1.Open()
                If prelease.Value = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Please Input a value on Release cannot proceed if the value is 0")
                ElseIf prelease.Value > 0 Then
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Item Has been Release in the inventory")
                End If
                conn1.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: please provide table sturctures

Comment: Look closely at `insert into puchase_report`.  The letter `r` is missing.  It should be `insert into purchase_report`.

Comment: oh, i didnt notice that. hahaha thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Chris R. Timmons Comments there was a 'r' mising in `INSERT INTO puchase_report` it should be `INSERT INTO purchase_report` As per OP Problem Solved.

```
Private Sub Button8_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click   
'''''''''''''''1st part'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim qtyrelease As Integer
qtyrelease = pqty.Text - prelease.Value


Dim release As String = String.Empty
release &= "update stocks set "
release &= "quantity=@qty "
release &= "where build_number=@build"

Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=pc_parts;user=admin;password=12345;")
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = release
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qtyrelease)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@build", pbuildnumber.Text)
        End With

        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Purchase Complete!")
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Using

'''''''''''''''2nd part''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim purchase As String = String.Empty
purchase &= "insert into purchase_report(buildnumber,pcbrand,pcpart,qty,date_purchase)"
purchase &= "values"
purchase &= "(@build1,@brand,@part,@quantity,@date)"

Using conn1 As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=purchase_stock;user=admin_report;password=54321;")
    Using cmd1 As New SqlCommand
        With cmd1
            .Connection = conn1
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = purchase
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@build1", pbuildnumber.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", pbrand.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@part", ppart.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", prelease.Value)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", pdate.Text)
        End With

        Try
            conn1.Open()
            If prelease.Value = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Please Input a value on Release cannot proceed if the value is 0")
            ElseIf prelease.Value > 0 Then
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Item Has been Release in the inventory")
            End If
            conn1.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        End Using
    End Using
   End Sub
```